# iPhone: How to get date and time from number of seconds?

Tags: iphone, time

I have time in seconds 1303093926 and I want to get date and time like

> Sat, 09 Oct 2010 18:14:50 +0000

Comment: The answer will vary depending on where you are getting the seconds. With your example, how are you getting 1303093926?

Comment: number of seconds begins from 1970

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NSDate has a conversion method:

```
double seconds = 1303093926;
NSTimeInterval timeInterval = (NSTimeInterval)seconds;
NSDate *date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:timeInterval];
```

You can then use the NSDateFormatter class to convert the NSDate to a string in the format you want.

Comment: @Moshe good point.  There are other conversion methods if the number of seconds starts from a different date.  See: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 0):

[NSDate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has several methods for creating date objects from second values. NSDate has four methods for doing exactly what you want:

- **+ (id)dateWithTimeInterval:(NSTimeInterval)seconds sinceDate:(NSDate *)date**: If your number of seconds is based on some arbitrary date, you would use this method.
- **+ (id)dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:seconds**: If your number of seconds is based on the time since 1970, then you would use this method.
- **+ (id)dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:(NSTimeInterval)seconds**: If the number of seconds is relative to the current time, use this. (Negative seconds are for dates prior to "now".)
- **+ (id)dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:(NSTimeInterval)seconds**: If you know that your number of seconds is relative to the predefined "reference date", (1 January 2001, GMT) then you should use this method.

Another approach, is to use [NSDateComponents](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to build your date object. From the NSDateComponents documentation:

```
NSDateComponents *comps = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
[comps setDay:6];
[comps setMonth:5];
[comps setYear:2004];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDate *date = [gregorian dateFromComponents:comps];
```

You can do the same with your number of seconds, using basic arithmetic to convert the seconds into years, months, days, hours, minutes and seconds.

Comment: thanks for your answer. my number of seconds begins from 1970. I will use this solution in future.